# PostGIS - Merge buffers geometry in different groups (when intersecting)

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis, qgis

I've  some geometries stored in this table (140k)

> CREATE TABLE buffers (pk integer NOT NULL,geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),)

[image: - buffers geometries from table "buffers" -]

and i would like to create (if possible) a new table (buffersmerged) that will contain the resultants geometries where the previews are **grouped** just when them are **intersecting** between each other.

My expected output, it is like when using in QGIS the Buffer(s) tool checking on "dissolve buffer results", but i would like, rather than just a big unique geometry as output, more small groups (one for each group of intersecting geometries)

[image: - this is the expected result -]

can you please help me to understand how can I construct a query that allows me to do that? (Postgres + PostGIS enabled)
Thank You

Stefano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the attributes too?

If not, this query should do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE buffersmerged AS 
SELECT (ST_dump(ST_union(a.geom))).geom 
FROM buffers a, buffers b 
WHERE ST_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) AND a.id != b.id;
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick reply.
No i didn't need any attributes, just the geometry.
Once i run your code, I've got a table that was looking good but without any geometry. What i've done to fix this (maybe in not a sexy way), was to create a table with already defined two column (pk, geom) where the second was already defined as POLYGON. And now it works!! Thanks

Comment: Strange, by me the statement worked. Maybe can you edit my answer and add your workaround? Don't forget to accept the answer, if it works.

Comment: before edit i'll show you the workaround:
>CREATE TABLE buffersmerged  (pk serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,geom geometry(POLYGON,4326));
and then:
>INSERT INTO  buffersmerged  (geom)
>SELECT (ST_dump(ST_union(a.geom))).geom
>FROM buffers a, buffers b 
>WHERE ST_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) AND a.pk != b.pk;
there is probably a way to make a single query, but i don't know how.
how to accept the answer? the upper arrow?

Comment: You need a.id< b.id instead of a.id != b.id, otherwise you get a double copy of grouped geometries.